# Real Analysis: Show that function is Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

[image]

This question somewhat confuses me with the function being defined as $1/x-1/x$,for $(0,1]$, and 0 where x=0.  I'm also somewhat thrown off about . meaning integer part.  Anyway, here is my attempt, which I am not sure if is correct:

Attempt:
The function is continuous at every point on [0,1]. except at x=0.
Lebesgue's Integrability Criterion states that a bounded function $f:[a,b]$ to $R$ is Riemann Integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere on [a,b].
The function given is bounded on the interval [0,1]. and the point of discontinuity, x=0, is a null set, where: [image].

Thus, the function is continuous almost everywhere on [0,1]. and hence is Riemann integrable.

Comment: A good attempt, but $f$ has a lot more discontinuities than just at $0$. For example, $\lim_{{x \rightarrow 1/2}^+}f(x) = 1$, but $\lim_{{x \rightarrow 1/2}^-}f(x) = 0$. Once you've actually found the set of discontinuities of $f$, the theorem you quoted will avail you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks.  Why is the limit as x goes to 1/2 from the right 1?

Comment: I thought it would also be 0?  Thanks.

Comment: For $x$ in $[1/2, \varepsilon)$, $f(x) = 1/x - 1$, As $x$ approaches $1/2$, $1/x$ approaches $2$, so $f(x)$ approaches $1$.

Comment: So I understand that as x approaches 1/2, 1/x approaches 2.  But, I am really confused by: for x in [1/2,e), f(x)=1/x-1.  How does f(x)=1/x-1?

Comment: @kemb Take for example $\;x=0.501\;$ , then $$\frac1x-\big\lfloor\frac1x\big\rfloor\approx1.99-1=0.99$$ and thus in the limit it equals $\;1\;$ . Try now from the left hand, say with $\;x=0.499\;$ ...

Comment: so do the brackets in [1/x] mean something?  Otherwise I'm not sure why [1/x] is approximately equal to 1?.  I get why 1/x is approximately equal to 1.99.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh wait, I get it now.  Thank you.  The brackets mean integer part.

Answer (score 2):

Updated Answer: The function is discontinuous at 0 and points of the form $1/n$, where n is a natural number, starting from 2,3....... (I believe the function is continuous at 1, that's why we start from 2).  This set is clearly countable and thus forms a null set (the set of discontinuities forms a null set).

Thus, by Lebesgue's Integrability Criterion, the function is Riemann integrable on [0,1]. I believe the function is bounded by 1 from above and 0 from below.